# WebMethod is returning name of variable, not the array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

This is driving me crazy... as part of another issue I've been working on ajax transfers to my mvc4 web app.

I've been working with this as an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692793/Introduction-to-Knockout-js-and-CRUD-Operations-in

The model is as follows:

```
    public class ColorList
{
    public int? ID;
    public string ColorName;
}
```

The controller function is as follows:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public ColorList[] GetAssignedColors(string szUserRecID)
    {
        int Rec = Convert.ToInt32(szUserRecID);
        var query = (from t in db.tblColors
                     join c in db.tblUser on t.fkColorID equals c.pkColorID
                     where t.fkRecID == Rec
                     select new ViewModels.ColorList()
                     {
                         ColorName = c.szColorName,
                         ID = t.ColorID
                     }).OrderBy(c => c.ColorName);
        //var q = query.ToArray(); // if I break and view q, the array exists
        return query.ToArray(); 
    }
```

Not sure this matters but here's my Ajax method:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAssignedColors", "EditColors")',
        data: { szUserRecID: RecID },
        success: function (results) {
            var colors = $.map(results.d, function (item) {
                return new Color(item)
            });
            self.CurrentColors(colors);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    })
```

**if I watch fiddler the response my code provides is (in text view):**

"**MyApps.ViewModels.ColorList[]**"

Not the array of colors as I am expecting.

Why is the function returning the variable name as an array instead of the array itself?

I've played around with this, but my ajax call doesn't seem to interpret the json response... However, the data shows in this instance but get a 200/ok with seemingly unusable data in my web page.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAssignedColors(string szUserRecID)
    {
        int Rec = Convert.ToInt32(szUserRecID);
        var query = (from t in db.tblColors
                     join c in db.tblUser on t.fkColorID equals c.pkColorID
                     where t.fkRecID == Rec
                     select new ViewModels.ColorList()
                     {
                         ColorName = c.szColorName,
                         ID = t.ColorID
                     }).OrderBy(c => c.ColorName);
        //var q = query.ToArray(); // if I break and view q, the array exists
        return Json(query.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Since formatting didn't work in the comments this is what worked; results didn't have the data necessary but "data" did.

```
     success: function (data) {
        var colors = $.map(data, function (item) {
            return new Color(item)
        });
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use the `WebMethodAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC. That attribute belongs to the ASP.NET Web Service technology (which is pretty dated by now). Regarding the second attempt, since you are using `POST` you don't need the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. Also, the parameter `szUserRecID` could be of type int instead of string, to let ASP.NET MVC do the modelbinding instead of doing the `Convert.ToInt32` yourself. Regarding the problem with the data in the AJAX call, have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the `success` callback function to see what data you have there?

Comment: Also, you write "doesn't seem to interpret the json response". Does this mean that you have inspected the `success` callback function and seen that the `results` parameter is a JSON string as opposed to an object? If so, have you checked the headers of the HTTP response? If you read the documentation on `jQuery.ajax()` it says that it will infer the data type based on headers from the HTTP response. If you want to force it to interpret it as a specific type, you could add the `dataType: 'json'` property to your AJAX options object.

Comment: I assume then I should be using the second function in my listing based on your first comment?

In regards to your second comment; How does one set a breakpoint in a javascript function in my cshtml?  They never get hit when I'm running in VS2012....  I still have the problem even though I have dataType: 'json' in my code.  Fiddler does report the data as json and I see the data in json format when inspecting.

Comment: Yes, the second version is the way to go if you want to use MVC (potentially you could look at WebAPI, ServiceStack or NancyFx, but MVC works). You can debug javascript with Visual Studio. How to do it should be pretty easy to find by searching on your favorite search engine. You could also use the built-in development tools in your browser (the later versions of all three have development tools built-in and I believe IE, Chrome and Firefox all open the development tools if you press F12) to debug javascript. Either of the two approaches would work to set a breakpoint in your javascript code.

Comment: Thanks Robert, you lead me to a major discovery.  Days of working on this issue.... I'll update the above with the format that succeeded.  Basically, results was not returning the data but the term data had what I needed.  I'm new to JS/ajax and this is quite frustrating working with.  I need to figure out the debugger; I'm coding in the blind without it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Write the final solution as an answer instead, so that you can accept your own answer and this question will be marked as answered with accepted answer.

Comment: By the way, the problem is not that `results` didn't work while `data` worked. They will have the exact same value. The problem was that your previous code used `results.d` while the current uses the `results` directly (though it is named `data`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  That was on my list to look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage I was working off of had:

```
 success: function (result) {
    var colors = $.map(result.d, function (item) {
        return new Color(item)
    });
```

The actual working method was:

```
 success: function (data) {
    var colors = $.map(data, function (item) {
        return new Color(item)
    });
```

I did not use the [webmethod] per Robert's wisdom and used the json response.

The final / working function was:
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetAssignedColors(string szUserRecID)
    {
        int Rec = Convert.ToInt32(szUserRecID);
        var query = (from t in db.tblColors
                     join c in db.tblUser on t.fkColorID equals c.pkColorID
                     where t.fkRecID == Rec
                     select new ViewModels.ColorList()
                     {
                         ColorName = c.szColorName,
                         ID = t.ColorID
                     }).OrderBy(c => c.ColorName);
        //var q = query.ToArray(); // if I break and view q, the array exists
        return Json(query.ToArray());

```
}
```

Note the removal of JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

thanks Robert!